# Android app downloading NULL data from remote mysql db

Tags: android, mysql, azure, android-studio, google-play

I'm new this Android world, and I'm facing a very peculiar issue these days and hence wanted to share with you. Please guide me if you know the solution.

I've installed and configured wampserver (mysql, php, apache) in remote Azure VM and I've opened all the ports for access. Please see the pics for Inbound and Outbound access.

[image]

[image]

Now the issue is: When I installed app in mobile (debug mode) through android studio and data cable, then it can both insert and fetch/download data from remote mysql db (through all php api scripts)… that means no issues in my app, php code, azure vm setup and access to it.

But when I published the same app in playstore and downloaded from there and installed in my same mobile, then its not able to fetch data, however it can insert data only into same mysql db. While fetching all php-apis are returning only null values, because of which all my recycler views are showing in mobile but with no data.

Anything should I take care in permission or in manifest file or where im missing ? please let me know if you know the answer. Thank you very much all in advance.

FYI, manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="31">
```

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.project.localshop'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.localshop"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 5
        versionName "3.2.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0'

    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0-alpha01'

    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'

    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:5.2.0"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
    //implementation 'com.cashfree.pg:android-sdk:1.7.28'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

Comment: Hi, Naresh! I suppose you use azure debug configuration for your project, and you need to set up production configs for Google Play. Please, check the azure guide that you have used. 
Another possibility is that usesCleartextTraffic flag may be the issue. On Android, it is preferred to use HTTPS over HTTP, and your production build may not work correctly. But it's just a guess.

Also, I recommend you try the production build without publishing to Google Play, so you can see if the problem comes from Google Play or the release build.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I checked all online materials, HTTP works fine in android app. If that was the sace, then it should fail during test run when installed from Android studio itself. Also, can you please elaborate this - need to set up production configs for Google Play ? I'm not getting hwo to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after a long search. The issue was with `minifyEnabled = true` option in `build.gradle` file. Make it `false`, so that android won't obfuscate the code, column names before sending it to database. But again, making it false is not good for app as others can decode and see your code from google Play Store. That's why make `minifyEnabled = true` and use a proper `R8` technique by adding `@Keep` keyword in your code functions.

For more details, watch this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgpyuuzMlo0